# Laravel 5.4 After loging out/in everything redirecting back to home

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am making an app using laravel 5.4. The first time I am logging in (using Auth) all links works fine, but after I logout/login everything is redirecting back to home page.
I've found out that if I delete the cookies from browser , it works again until next logout! But I need cookies so can not disable them. 
Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `SESSION_DRIVER` in your env file?

Comment: You will get a much better response here on SO if you read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide. Specifically, you might want to tell us if you are using the standard out-of-the-box auth stuff from Laravel, or if you've customised it somehow.  You might want to show us [the simplest bit of code you can create which demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Good luck.

Comment: @BharatGeleda  SESSION_DRIVER=file

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for advices , right now it just regular Auth